# Why do we use setAuthCookies in MVC form authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc

`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(data.EmployeeEmail, false);`

`FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(data.EmployeeName, false);`

I am confused by these two lines, can anyone explain their purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put simply...

`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie();` sets an encrypted cookie on the users browser when they have been signed in. The server then uses this cookie to identify a users session each time a request is made to the server. Essentially it tells the server that this user is authenticated.

`FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage();` will redirect the user to the page they originally tried to access before they signed in. If you have a url that is only accessible to authenticated users, and an **un**authenticated user tries to access it directly - they will instead be directed to the login page. Once authenticated calling `RedirectFromLoginPage` will return them to the original url. You can normally see the original url stored as a query string on the login page when this occurs.

Comment: Hi Sean T
Thanks for helping me out.
I just wanted to ask about FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage();
that where should I set my path of login page.

I have form authentication where I have set my urls

 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" defaultUrl="~/Login/Something" 
                  protection="All">
     </forms>
</authentication>

Comment: See here... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirectfromloginpage?view=netframework-4.7.2